# Powershell script to update session store section under system.web section in a web.config file

Tags: powershell, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

```
...
<system.web>
    ...other nodes..

    <sessionState timeout="10" mode="Custom" customProvider="PROVIDER_NAME">
      <providers>
        <add name="PROVIDER_NAME" type="PROVIDER_TYPE" throwOnError="true" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" databaseId="0" applicationName="AppNAME" connectionString="CONNECTION_STRING" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

    ..other nodes...
  </system.web>
```

I have the above entry in the web.config file. I like to update the connection string in the above node using a powershell script. The change should only affect the connection string alone not any other nodes/attributes. My app is hosted in azure. I know connecting to azure app and update app setting like below.

```
$app = Set-AzureRMWebApp -Name $name -ResourceGroupName $group **-AppSettings $mysettingsCollection** -- this works fine
```

But I am not sure about updating specific node in an xpath. Please provide some sample scripts if possible. Something similar ->

```
$app = Set-AzureRMWebApp -Name $name -ResourceGroupName $group -**SYSTEM.WEB/SESSIONSATE VALUES**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell will not let you do this. The way to get this done properly is through an XDT transform. [You can read more about using XDT transforms here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples)

The thing to understand is that for an App Service app, there is a config object that is a subset of web.config. so things like app settings, connection strings and some other common sections are part of this config object.

This way, you can add "app settings", or override an item in web.config with what you have in the configuration for your app.

specifically session state, this is not an element we have in the configuration of the app. so the fall back here is web.config therefore the need for the XDT transform.

In t his case the XDT transform would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="10" mode="Custom" customProvider="PROVIDER_NAME">
            <providers>
                <add name="PROVIDER_NAME" type="PROVIDER_TYPE" throwOnError="true" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" databaseId="0" applicationName="AppNAME" connectionString="CONNECTION_STRING" />
          </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Based on your input I decided to not to store the connection string in this way. I change to get the connection string via C# code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a single Azure Web Apps connection string while maintaining all other connection strings, you need to pass in the values for ALL the Connection Stings in the save call using the Set-AzureRmWebApp cmdlet. To do this you must first iterate through the entire list of existing Connection Strings and add them to the Hash collection before adding or setting specific Connection String values on the Hash collection.

Please make sure that none of the existing connection strings are removed when making an update to one or more connection strings on an Azure Web App:

```html
# Load Existing Web App settings
$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyWebApp" -Slot production

# Get reference to the existing Connection Strings
$existingConnectionStrings = $webApp.SiteConfig.ConnectionStrings

# Create Hash variable for Connection Strings
$hash = @{}

# Copy over all Existing Connection Strings to the Hash
ForEach($connString in $existingConnectionString) {
$hash[$connString.Name] = @{ Type = $connString.Type.ToString(); Value = $connString.ConnectionString }
}

# Add or Update a desired Connection String within the Hash collection
$hash["AppConnString"] = @{ Type = "SqlAzure"; Value = "conn-string-here" }

# Save Connection String to Azure Web App
Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyWebApp" -Slot production -ConnectionStrings $hash
```

This is an important tip to remember when adding or updating Connection Strings on an Azure Web App using the PowerShell cmdlets. If you forget you may just accidentally delete all the other Connection Strings for the application in the event there are more existing Connection Strings than you are adding or updating. Don’t break production, and please remember to use this tip!

For more details, refer to this blog post: [Easily Manage Azure Web App Connection Strings using PowerShell](https://www.opsgility.com/blog/2017/01/20/easily-manage-azure-web-app-connection-strings-using-powershell/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Ashok for your valuable time and response.. This code will update the connection string in the connection string section of the config file However I wanted to update an attribute (CONNECTION STRING) of an xml element located at the xpath configuration\system.web\sessionState\providers\add[@name=PR‌​OVIDER_NAME] in the web.config file. NOTE: This is an azure hosted MVC5.net webapp. Could you assist ?